# Is synthetic sapphire as kasherable as the natural version?

Tags: halacha, kashering-kosherization, gemstone

I understand that stone may be kashered for dishware. Although expensive, natural sapphire is considered stone. The chemical formula for sapphire is corundum, aluminum oxide, doped with elements for colors. There now exists an inexpensive process to fuse aluminum oxide powder into man-made sapphire for art projects, involving microwave heating. May I use this source as a material for creating kasherable dishware, on the general Torah grounds that something chemically the same, is the same?

Comment: Your bounty shows that you need a halachic psak, something this site does not provide. Contact your local Orthodox rabbi or search for one online.

Comment: Corundum is as impermeable as glass due to its tight crystal structure and therefore should have the same *halacha* as glass. So in cases (and according to *poskim*) where glass is considered impermeable, corundum should be considered impermeable also.

Comment: But Ashkenazi rabbis consider glass to be non kasherable for dining ware. I was hoping artificial sapphire would be better than glass since natural sapphire is considered stone by same. Mere glass is considered permeable here. So this doesn't answer my question. Sorry.

Comment: A stone is part of a rock. A rock is a conglomeration of minerals. Corundum is a mineral in crystalline form, not a rock (or stone).

Comment: Do the scholars yet recognize that something chemically the same is also the same halachically?